# yii 2 последняя миграция не записывается в таблицу migrate

Tags: yii2, миграция

Запускаю миграции yii2 на пустой базе они проходят, но последняя не записывается в таблицу migrate и при следующем запуске она второй раз запускается и не проходит т.к. уже в первый раз прошла.
как сделать чтобы она с первого раза попадала в таблицу migration

Comment: и ошибок не выдаёт никаких? а что внутри миграции написано? а если откатить и накатить опять?

Comment: ошибок не выдает, там куча миграций но я выяснил что ломает все миграция с методом execute, а как исправить пока не знаю

Comment: покажите её.... возможно ещё надо будет содержание таблиц..

Comment: Точно в таблицу миграция не записывается? Потому что если не записывалась, то она не может не проходить. Потому что ориентир того прошла миграция или нет всегда на то, что имеется в таблице миграций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в одной из миграций выполнялся нативный SQL запрос и там была строчка SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0; из-за нее не записывалась последняя миграция в таблицу migrate

Comment: Сработало! Спасибо!